# How do I decouple wasm specific macros from functions and structs

Tags: rust, webassembly, serde, wasm-bindgen

I've got some core functionality, primarily an algorithm that i'm trying to reuse in web assembly and java.

I'm using wasm-bindgen and serde, I notice that wasm-bindgen and serde is tightly coupled to my algorithm via the use of attributes. i.e; `#[wasm_bindgen]` and `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]` -- i'm quite new to rust so i'm wondering how I can decouple these attributes from my function and struct so that I can reuse my functions and structs in my implementation that will interface with java. At the moment because they're tightly coupled if I was to try and use these functions on a platform that isn't wasm it'll throw a panic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serialize` and `Deserialize` are not specific to wasm and are available on other platforms.

For `wasm_bindgen`, you can use the [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) attribute to only define it for the `wasm` platform if you replace `#[wasm_bindgen` with `#[cfg_attr (wasm, wasm_bindgen)]`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at cfg_attr, a quick question regarding cfg_attr. If I have a cfg_attr that evaluates to false does that mean I can still call the underlying function that the cfg_attr is for, it just won't have the attribute applied?

Comment: Yes `cfg_attr` is for conditioning the attributes themselves. If you want to completely enable or disable the function, you have to use the `cfg` attribute.